# How to install openCV library on Mac OS X 10.6.8

Tags: macos, opencv

I am new to openCV. How do I install this library on Mac OS X 10.6.8 and how do I include it in Xcode?

Comment: Any joy installing OpenCV ?

Comment: No George.. can u please tell me how to install openCV in xcode, step by step.

Answer (score 2):

Start with one thing at a time:

1. Install OpenCV
2. Setup an XCode project

The easiest way is to install OpenCV is via [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/). 
Make sure you've installed **XCode's Command Line Tools** first!

```
sudo port install opencv
```

note that you can also use ports variants (to add extra features e.g. python and QT support)

```
sudo port install opencv +qt4 +python27
```

As of very recently there should also be [OpenNI support](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/35512) in MacPorts.

The other option is to build from source using Terminal. You'd also need [CMake](http://cmake.org/) on top of XCode Command Line Tools

Regarding using OpenCV in XCode, it's a matter of making a c++ project and setting up the header and library search paths for the projects. If you use Macports those would be `/opt/local/include/` and `/opt/local/lib`